# best way to implement facebook api in cocos 2d

Tags: ios, facebook, api, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying hard to find a way to implement the Facebook api in cocos 2d, but I was not able to find one.

Anyone may help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this, is with a singleton model object using something like a "shared instance" function.

That way, as the app goes about its business and you don't actively need FB, you can leave your session available on the side and call it as follows.

```
//create a static void

static FacebookModel *sharedInstance = nil;

//In the model
+(FacebookModel *) sharedInstance {

if (sharedInstance == nil) {
<INSTANTIATE FACEBOOK with an FB property>
<LOG INTO FACEBOOK with that property>
    }
return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)selectorWhichPostsToFacebook {
<USE CODE HERE TO POST TO FB>
>

//In your view did load for any class that needs it...
FacebookModel *fM = [FacebookModel sharedInstance];

//then when you need to actually use fb to do something...
[fM selectorWhichPostsToFB];
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I am new at it, I don't know how to make it works, to make a log-in, autenticate, etc. I'm trying to learn FQL, but I don't know if it can solve my implementation problem.

Comment: if you'd kindly accept this answer though, i would appreciate it! The developers site within facebook has sample code which is fairly easy to digest. You can also look into leveraging parse (www.parse.com) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I'll try to list what I need to do.
Make the facebook login.
Share Image, link. Tag people.
know which account is logged in.